# How can I get the function to add the sum of the true properties in the output?

Tags: python, sum

```
def large_sum(lst, num): 
    def larger(x):
        return (int(x) > num)
    m = list(map(larger,lst))  
    print(m)

large_sum([2,4,6,8,10], 7)
# [False, False, False, True, True]
```

I wish to get the sum of the element in `[2,4,6,8,10]` where `m` is `True`.

Comment: Do you want to sum the elements that are greater than `num`?

Comment: Yes, I do, but when I put print(sum(m)) it outputs 2 and not 18

Comment: Try `sum(i for i in [2,4,6,8,10] if i > 7)`

Comment: Chris' answer is good. You could refactor the function: `def large_sum(nums: list, threshold: int) -> int: return sum(n for n in nums if n > threshold)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) in the following way:

```
from itertools import compress

def large_sum(lst, num): 
    def larger(x):
        return (int(x) > num)
    m = list(map(larger,lst))  
    return m
l = [2,4,6,8,10]
n = 7
res = large_sum(l, n)
print(sum(list(compress(l, res)))
```

I kept the original logic, but I would suggest to use @chris method as it would be better efficency-wise:

```
l = [2,4,6,8,10]
n = 7
sum(i for i in l if i > n)
```

Answer (score 1):

The main thing is to use `filter` instead of `map`:

```
def large_sum(lst, num):
    def larger(x):
        return x > num
    return sum(filter(larger, lst))

print(large_sum([2,4,6,8,10], 7))
# 18
```

`map` transforms each value in the list, into a boolean in this case. The original values are not there anymore, and if you `sum` the booleans, `True` is converted to 1 and `False` to 0, which is why you get 2.

`filter`, on the other hand, returns the original values, but only those for which the predicate (`larger` in this case) returns `True`, and omits the others. Then you just `sum` those.